# Parsing Google Maps API GeoCode - server side or client side?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, client-side, geocoding, server-side

With this url:

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=31.376356,34.811039&sensor=false

I can obtain the type of the location (road, street etc.).

1. Is there any other solution?
2. If I use on server side, it's going to consume the company queries, right?

   - If so, doing it on client side consume the client queries?

My goal is obtaining the type of coordinate (road, street etc) preferably on server side without consume the company queries.

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this a website or an application that you need to hit geocoding servers on every request? If so, you should use client-side.

If you have some predefined latLng values then you can use server side geocoding and cache the results for a couple of hours. This way, you probably won't need to worry about quota.

From Google Developers' site:

> When to Use Client-Side Geocoding
>
> The basic answer is "almost always." As geocoding limits are per user
>   session, there is no risk that your application will reach a global
>   limit as your userbase grows. Client-side geocoding will not face a
>   quota limit unless you perform a batch of geocoding requests within a
>   user session. Therefore, running client-side geocoding, you generally
>   don't have to worry about your quota.

See [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#quota-limits)